# Debugging Assembly Code (Intel 8086)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assembly, debugging

I'm in an Assembly class focusing on the intel 8086 architecture (all compiling / linking / execution comes from running DOS on win7 via DOS-Box).

I've finished programming the latest assignment, but as I have yet to program *any* program successfully the first time through, I am now stuck trying to debug my code.

I have visual studio 2010 and was wondering if there was some built in feature that would help me debug my assembly code, specifically, I'm looking to track the value of a variable.

Failing that, instructions pointing to a DOS-Box debugger (and instructions!) would be much appreciated. (I *think* I've been able to run codeview debug, but I couldn't figure out how to  do what I was looking for).

Comment: Can you post the code you have, will give it a try in free time?

Comment: the code is pretty complex, ~160 lines or so, so if you have a suggestion as to where to post it, I certainly shall, but I'm not going to clutter my question with it needlessly.

Comment: If you're in an Assembly class, does the teacher not recommend a toolset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, indeed, you can use the debugger in VS to examine pretty much everything.  Irvine's site has a section specifically on using the debugger [here](http://kipirvine.com/asm/debug/vstudio2010/index.htm).  You can examine registers, use the watch window, etc.  He also has a guide for highlighting asm keywords if you need that.

Edit: as Hans pointed out, if you are using 16-bit instead of 32-bit protected, you'll need different tools.  There are several choices, listed [here](http://kipirvine.com/asm/debug/).

Answer (score 3):

You are generating 16-bit code, you have to break into a museum to find better tooling.  Try [Borland's](http://edn.embarcadero.com/museum/), maybe the debugger included with Turbo C.

Comment: I've never tried it, but I know people who used to rave about Watcom's compiler, which has since become open-source, including the assembler: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Watcom_Assembler

Answer (score 1):

Borland's tools for DOS were called [tasm, tlink, and tdebug](http://ece.wpi.edu/~wrm/Courses/EE2801/Labs/tasm).